# Way can I not see The Property Setting

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS report with a list I have added a row group to group the list by names and now need place some page breaks in so each name will start on a new page.  I have enables the advance mode in the column group and then select the Name in the row group.  When I inspect the properties for the name row I am not seeing the "RepeatOnNewPage" as one of the settings.  Any idea why I am not seeing these options?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're right enabling the Advance Mode, but you should click the "Static", instead of the row groups.

Comment: When I click the static in the columns group I get an error message from what I have found it is due to a lack of column headers.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the report was corrupted the only fix was to delete and start over again.